# xsd:extension not working: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'BaseObj' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: xml, xslt

BaseObj.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://dummy/models/BaseObj" 
    targetNamespace="http://dummy//models/BaseObj" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="bo" type="BaseObj" />
    <xsd:complexType name="BaseObj">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="one" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence> 
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

ChildObj.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://dummy/models/ChildObj"
    targetNamespace="http://dummy/models/ChildObj" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://dummy/models/BaseObj" schemaLocation="BaseObj.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="co" type="ChildObj" />
    <xsd:complexType name="ChildObj">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BaseObj">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="two" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>`
```

`

When processing the above ChildObj doesn't recognize BaseObj and throws Cannot resolve the name 'BaseObj' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
From what I understand I imported the needed schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your XSDs:

1. In `BaseObj.xsd` your

   ```
   targetNamespace="http://dummy//models/BaseObj"
   ```

   contains a superfluous `/`. Change it to

   ```
   targetNamespace="http://dummy/models/BaseObj"
   ```
2. In `ChildObj.xsd` you didn't define a namespace for your `BaseObj` element. It looks like

   ```
   <xsd:extension base="BaseObj">
   ```

   To fix this, add a namespace declaration to your `xsd:schema` element like

   ```
   ... xmlns:base="http://dummy/models/BaseObj" ...
   ```

   and then change the above `xsd:extension` to

   ```
   <xsd:extension base="base:BaseObj">
   ```

Now your schemas should validate as expected.

Comment: Aha..yes missed the namespace. Thanks for the help!